# Algorithm for maximum bipartite matching with arriving edges?

Tags: matching, dynamic-algorithms, bipartite-graphs

Given a bipartite graph with fixed nodes and incrementally arriving edges, is there any efficient algorithm to compute and update the maximum matching?

Comment: https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/focs/2014/6517/00/6517a384.pdf

Comment: This paper assumes the nodes on the left side are arriving. It is different problem setting from mine.

Comment: @Chuancong, I think you should update your questions explaining in it why the solution in the link Neal provided does answer yours. That way people can tailor their comments and answers to the question you really want an answer for.